# Delete all files in a web directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web directory that contains files and I want to delete them all. I've looked online but all the answers rely on the file system and I want to use the website's directories. I tried this:

```
foreach (string file in HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\MyDirectory"))
{
     File.Delete(file);
}
```

The foreach statement is underlined and the error is `'cannot convert type char to string'.`

What's the syntax to delete all files in a directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your might need to correct your MapPath parameter (\\MyDirectory), but the syntax you need is shown below.

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di= new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\MyDirectory"));

foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
{
  file.Delete(); 
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks; your answer helped me rewrite my code like this: Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\MyDirectory")), File.Delete);

Answer (score 1):

Server.MapPath gives you a directory path, not an array of files/folders.  IF you want to remove all files in the folder you would do this:

```
var folderPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\MyDirectory");
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(folderPath))
{
    File.Delete(file);
}
```

If you wanted do delete the folder, then

```
var folderPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\MyDirectory");
Directory.Delete(folderPath);
```

To delete all folders within the main folder

```
var folderPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\MyDirectory");
foreach (string file in Directory.GetDirectoriesfolderPath))
{
    File.Delete(file);
}
```